# Discord @commands.has_role(role) change reference

Tags: discord.py

so I am building a small verification bot, that you can start in the guild but then private messages you to continue. Each stage of the process needs some user input or validation so I thought of handling each stage through roles. Now to finish up the bot I planned to make each command only accessible if the user has a specific role.

Now to the issue, in the DMS the user does not have roles!

I made a role handler that refers to the user in the guild to give and remove roles in the DMS but that does not seem to work for the decorators.

So long story short, how do I have the @commands.has_role(role) decorator refer to the user in the guild??

Thank you all very much in advance for the help.

Best Regards

```
@commands.has_role("Verf Stage 2") #Issue
@slash.slash(
    name="IamReady",
    description="Allows you to continue with the verification.",
    guild_ids=guildIds,
    permissions = permission2     
)

async def _IamReady(ctx:SlashContext):
    global user_obj
    role = "Verf Stage 2"
    await ctx.author.send('Let me see what i can find')
    username = user_obj.usrname
    #For testing
    tempateId = os.getenv('TEMPLATE_ID_TEST')
    state = await getUserData(userName = username, templateId = tempateId)
    if state == "NoAssetfound":
        pass
    elif state == "Usernotfound":
        pass
    else:
        nftemebed = await getNftEmbed(state)
        user_obj.assetId = state['asset_id']
        # Addrole
        await rolehandler(user = user_obj.auth, newrole = role, guild = bot.get_guild(id=guildIds[-1]))
    await ctx.author.send(embed = nftemebed)
```

P.S. Work in progress

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this instance you are correct the user is a `user` object and not a `member` object.

I would find the appropriate guild and use `member=guild.get_member(int(user.id))` to get the member object you need and then `if role in member.roles` to test for the role from a DM.